# No path found between two points

Tags: grass-gis, ubuntu, shortest-path, nodes

I'm trying to find a path between different pairs of points,
But within the thousands of pairs tried only a few actually result in a path.
I find this odd but maybe it's normal.
(note that when I'm activating turntable (generated from GRASS GIS itself) it only find one segment long path (so it's useless))
Do you have any ideas?

I'm using [v.net.path](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.net.path.html) with a file containing start and end points.
I also found that part of the problem might be due to roundabout but I'm unsure.
The map was filtered to "remove duplicates" but I don't see how this would cause a problem.

Comment: @BERA no I'm using GRASS GIS 7.8.7 (no tools that I'm aware of).
Should I be using QGIS or any tool?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Did you prepare the network with v.net (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.net.html)?